# Aria Hidden field not toggling tabbed content with ACF repeater

Tags: javascript, php, advanced-custom-fields, addeventlistener

I am trying to build tabbed content using the ACF repeater field.

I have done this before, but never with a repeater.

I have managed to get the buttons and panels to marry up using php counters but for some reason, the hidden field does not get removed off the previous tab content, it just adds the new tabs content below.

This so far has been a small feat for me but I can't work what is wrong.

I would also like the first iteration of the button to have. tabindex of 0.

Any help greatly appreciated

```
<div class="tabsnew" id="newtabsblock">
                <div role="tablist" class="tabs-left-new" aria-label="Tabbed information tabs">
                    
                    <?php
                    $panel=1;
                    $tab=1;
                    ?>
                    
                    <?php if ( have_rows( 'tabbed_content' ) ) : ?>
                            
                            <?php while ( have_rows( 'tabbed_content' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
                                <button class="tab-button-new" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="panel-<?php echo $panel++; ?>" id="tab-<?php echo $tab++; ?>" tabindex="-1">
                                        <?php the_sub_field('pre_defined_tabs'); ?>
                                </button>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <?php // No rows found ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                        
                </div>
            </div>  
            
            
            <div class="panels-new">
                
                    <?php 
                    $contentpanel=1;
                    $contenttab=1;
                    ?>
                    
                    <?php if ( have_rows( 'tabbed_content' ) ) : ?>
                                <?php while ( have_rows( 'tabbed_content' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
                                    <div id="panel-<?php echo $contentpanel++; ?>" role="tabpanel" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="tab-<?php echo $contenttab++; ?>" hidden>
                                        <?php the_sub_field( 'tabbed-content-text' ); ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <?php // No rows found ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
            
             </div>
```

JS

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('[role="tab"]');
  const tabList = document.querySelector('[role="tablist"]');

  // Add a click event handler to each tab
  if(tabs) {
      tabs.forEach((tab) => {
        tab.addEventListener('click', changeTabs);
      });
  }

  // Enable arrow navigation between tabs in the tab list
  let tabFocus = 0;

  if(tabList) {
    tabList.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        // Move right
        if (e.keyCode === 39 || e.keyCode === 37) {
        tabs[tabFocus].setAttribute('tabindex', -1);
        if (e.keyCode === 39) {
            tabFocus++;
            // If we're at the end, go to the start
            if (tabFocus >= tabs.length) {
            tabFocus = 0;
            }
            // Move left
        } else if (e.keyCode === 37) {
            tabFocus--;
            // If we're at the start, move to the end
            if (tabFocus < 0) {
            tabFocus = tabs.length - 1;
            }
        }

        tabs[tabFocus].setAttribute('tabindex', 0);
        tabs[tabFocus].focus();
        }
    });
  }

});

function changeTabs(e) {
  const target = e.target;
  const parent = target.parentNode;
  const grandparent = parent.parentNode;

  // Remove all current selected tabs
  parent
    .querySelectorAll('[aria-selected="true"]')
    .forEach((t) => t.setAttribute('aria-selected', false));

  // Set this tab as selected
  target.setAttribute('aria-selected', true);

  // Hide all tab panels
  grandparent
    .querySelectorAll('[role="tabpanel"]')
    .forEach((p) => p.setAttribute('hidden', true));

  // Show the selected panel
  grandparent.parentNode
    .querySelector(`#${target.getAttribute('aria-controls')}`)
    .removeAttribute('hidden');
}
```

UPDATE

So I have managed to get the tab-index and aria-selected values to display correctly but it still does not remove the hidden class.

```
<div class="tabsnew" id="newtabsblock">
            <div role="tablist" class="tabs-left-new" aria-label="Tabbed information tabs">
                
                <?php
                $panel=1;
                $tab=1;
                $i=0;
                ?>
                
                <?php if ( have_rows( 'tabbed_content' ) ) : ?>
                        
                        <?php while ( have_rows( 'tabbed_content' ) ) : the_row(); $i++; ?>
                            <button class="tab-button-new" role="tab" aria-selected="<?php if( $i ==1 ){ echo "true"; } else { echo "false"; } ?>" aria-controls="panel-<?php echo $panel++; ?>" id="tab-<?php echo $tab++; ?>" tabindex="<?php if( $i ==1 ){ echo "0"; } else { echo "-1"; } ?>">
                                    <?php the_sub_field('pre_defined_tabs'); ?>
                            </button>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php // No rows found ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                    
            </div>
        </div>  
        
        
        <div class="panels-new">
            
                <?php 
                $contentpanel=1;
                $contenttab=1;
                $row=1;
                ?>
                
                <?php if ( have_rows( 'tabbed_content' ) ) : ?>
                            <?php while ( have_rows( 'tabbed_content' ) ) : the_row(); $row++; ?>
                                <div id="panel-<?php echo $contentpanel++; ?>" role="tabpanel" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="tab-<?php echo $contenttab++; ?>" <?php if( $row !=2 ){ echo "hidden"; } ?>>
                                    <?php the_sub_field( 'tabbed-content-text' ); ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php // No rows found ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
        
         </div>
```